# Regarding type in python

Tags: python

Here is the code:

```
class D(object):
   def __init__(self):
      print 'D'

   def test(self):
      print 'test'

def main():
   a = {}
   a = D()
   a.test()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

The variable `a` is originally dict but is assigned a type of `class D`. Then `a` becomes a `class D` instance. In python can one type be converted to any other type? Thanks.

Comment: No, it cannot .

Comment: No. Python  variables do not have type. Python is a dynamic language.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. In Python you can reassign any value of any type to a name (variable) but that is not a conversion.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't do what you think it does. Here firstly you created a object of `dict` with reference `a`. Then on doing `a = D()`; you replaced `a` with the reference of object of class `D()`.

In Python for converting the type; you have to type-cast the object as:

```
# `float` to `int`
>>> float_value = 1.67   # `float` type
>>> int(float_value)
1    # `int` type

# `list` to `dict`
>>> my_list = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]  # `list` type
>>> dict(my_list)
{1: 2, 3: 4}    # `dict` type
```

Note: Conversion should be logically correct. For example: converting string character to `int` will give the values error as:

```
>>> int('a')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

> In python can one type be converted to any other type?

Yes. Python provides several different functions to convert one data type to another. As long as the conversion is logically correct. Functions such as `str()`, `int()`, `bool()`, `float()`, etc...

However, if your question is:

> Can I change the data type of a variable to another?

Then that is something different entirely.

Python is a *dynamically* typed language. This means that variables' datatypes can change anytime in the program.  Unlike *statically* typed languages, variables in Python are not bound to a particular data type or object.

Unlike most statically typed languages which require you to *cast* a variable to a different datatype and/or value, in Python you can simply reassign a variable a different value via the assignment operator(`=`).

You could think of this way. Variables in Python are *references*. When you assign a variable to a certain value, the variable now *refers* to that value. But because that variable is simply a reference, and not bound to the value, you change it to refer to a different value.